# Convert GD image back to binary data

Tags: php, image, gd

I have a GD image resource created from `imagecreatefromstring`. After some image operations, I want to convert it back to binary data. How would I do this? Can't see any functions in the manual...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [imagejpeg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), [imagepng](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php), or similar. Use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) if you want to dump the result to a string, rather than a file:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($im);
$image_string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: change ob_end_flush() to ob_end_clean() if you don't want the buffer echo'd

Answer (score 5):

```
function image_data($gdimage)
{
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($gdimage);
    return(ob_get_clean());
}
```